# can't access boostrap.css file in codeigniter for strange 403 error

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to access the boostrap.min.css file from one of my page and i am getting the following error

> "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden -
>   http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/application/assets/css/boostrap.min.css

i have loaded my url helper in config.php file.And trying to access the path to boostrap file like the following in my controller

```
class User extends CI_Controller{


    public function index(){

       $this->load->view('users/user_index');
    }

}
```

user_index page in view:

```
<?php


?>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("ci/application/assets/css/boostrap.min.css"); ?>">
</head>
<body>
<h1>user index</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Never encountered this type of error before.How i can fix this?

Comment: isn't it due to typo in bootstrap.min.css (you typed boostrap.min.css)?

Answer (score 6):

Your assets folder should be outside the application folder.

For security purposes the htaccess in the application folder prevents it.

Note: It is also a good practice to keep your application folder and system folder above the web root and change the path in index.php for production purposes

Comment: why it should be outside?

Comment: @AL-zami because the htaccess file inside the application folder blocks it so all css files images etc should be located out side the application folder.